# Galois Theory - Permutations of a Rational Roots Polynomial (mindless typo)

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, permutations, galois-theory

So in Galois Theory, given a polynomial, say of the second degree, the permutation of the roots compose the Galois Group if their algebraic relation holds true when we transpose the roots.
If I am understanding this correctly then given a polynomial with roots A,B:

```
A+B=1 & B+A=1 then (A B) & (B A) e Galois Group
```

I can't understand why in a rational root polynomial, the group generated is trivial. How does that work? Isn't the inverse still an inverse and different than the identity?

(sorry I don't get the math syntax here yet)

Comment: ..."roots are part of the Galois Group..." This is to vague, and the reader wants a clear question with clear data. Which Galois Group? What does it mean "*are part*"? Where does the polynomial come in? Try to give an example... E.g. for $x^2-7$ over $\Bbb Q$, the roots are $\pm \sqrt 7$ (in some field...) and the Galois group has two elements, the identity of the field $F=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 7)$ and the automorphism of $F$ determined by $\sqrt 7\to-\sqrt 7$. Which is here the question? If the polynomial is split over $\Bbb Q$, e.g. $(x-3)(x-986)$, then which is the splitting field of it?

Comment: The Galois groups are not necessarily trivial. Automorphisms send a root to another root which can be irrational as shown above.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I mindlessly typed 'coefficient' when I meant 'root' :)